# Why can't I convert my R data to SPSS due to invalid format?

Tags: r, spss

I want to import a R file into SPSS. I used the following code for this:

```
library(foreign)
write.foreign(mydata, "C:\\Users\\LM\\OneDrive\\Documents\\mydata.txt", 
              "C:\\Users\\LM\\OneDrive\\Documents\\mydata.sps", package="SPSS")
```

Then I opened the syntax document that was made. When I run this in SPSS I get the following error:

> Error # 4130 in column 41.  Text: .
>
> The DATA LIST command contains an invalid format.
>
> Execution of this command stops.`

What went wrong?

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: All there is in de syntax is: ENCODING="Locale" / my variables (F8.0). I now see that there is an variable called filter_. and one calle .id . Maybe the dots are the problem?

Comment: The help file states: For package="SPSS", as a side effect, the decimal indicator is always set by SET DECIMAL=DOT. which may override user settings of the indicator or its default derived from the current locale.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this? @James

Comment: Edit the sps file to remove or amend it perhaps?

Comment: It appears to be an issue with syntax in the DATA LIST command. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.reference/spss/base/syn_data_list_examples.htm#syn_data_list_examples Similar example from a different forum: http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Data-creation-td5732065.html

Answer (score 0):

You've already identified your answer -- In this case it is likely the leading period and not the trailing period that fails in your variable name.  In any case, leading and trailing periods should be avoided in SPSS Statistics variable names.

See the IBM SPSS Statistics Command Syntax Reference Guide: Universals section -
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_variables_variable_names.html

[image]

Several sources provide examples on how to rename your columns in an  R dataframe.  Here is one:
http://rprogramming.net/rename-columns-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

You might find the STATS GET R extension command useful. It can be installed from the Extensions > Extension Hub menu.